# Adding Tester to TestFlight

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program, testflight

If I add a tester to TestFlightApp.com They get a link to register their device. This then downloads a profile, which is called TestFlight Access. Not for my app.

What is this profile for and how does it relate to my app?

Also do I still need to add the tester's UDID to the apple developer portal, myself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That profile allows the service to gather the UDID of the testers device. This way the user never has to manually search that UDID and it is possible for the service to provide developers who invite users that information automatically.

Additionally, the installed web clip will authenticate the device against the service, so the apps that can be installed will be offered. These apps are found by comparing the UDID of the device against the provisioning profiles of all apps available.

So yes, you still need to add the UDID to the provisioning profile and compile your app against it.

The profile process is provided by Apple and well documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505

There are also other services who leverage that functionality for "easier" gathering of UDIDs and providing an easy way to let users download their beta apps.

Answer (score 4):

I'm jumping in here to say, yes you do need to re-build your app with a new profile that includes the new tester's device UDID. I'm having a problem with this for one tester only, that no matter what I do TestFlight refuses to acknowledge that the profile I am using has this one person's UDID in it yet it does. I'm writing to their support group about it and will let the forum know what I find out if anything useful.

Comment: I saw they just had an outage. Are you sure you're 1) adding to member center on iPhone 2) downloading final prov. profile 3) uploading to testflight the provisioning profile 4) re-archiving with profile set in xCode (god this process is long and convoluted)  5) uploading new ipa with new profile

Answer (score 1):

The profile allows the test flight app to install your app. And yes, you will still need to add their UDID to the provisioning profile.

Comment: So that means I have to rebuild the app, and upload it, every time I add a tester?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746988/publishing-to-testflight-new-testers-do-i-really-need-to-rebuild-download-my-p.