# If a UDID is added to an existing provisioning profile, does the IPA require regeneration?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, testflight

I see a lot of questions that ask how to add a UDID to an existing provisioning profile, but I haven't been able to find any info on whether or not that requires any IPAs using it to be recreated.

So for example if I...

1. Create an ad-hoc provisioning profile "Internal Testers" with just me in it
2. Export an application using that profile and put it up on testflightapp.com
3. Add an additional UDID to my "Internal Testers" provisioning profile

Do I need to re-create the IPA? If the UDIDs end up stored inside the IPA, I'd imagine yes. If the UDIDs are stored online and referenced, I'd imagine no. However, no one seems to have any documentation on which way it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you do need to recreate the `ipa` after editing the `provisional profile`

Comment: While this is correct, it seems that you can also just update the provision part (without having to upload the entire binary again). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201934/1060650

Comment: This answer is wrong since you can upload a new provisioning profile without recreating the IPA file. When you do this on testflight it doesn't change the IPA at all, it just installs the updated profile on the device before downloading the IPA, which still contains the old profile.

Comment: @Gavin - yes but that ipa wont include the new UDID. In order to use the ipa on the new device, you will need to recreate the provisioning profile and create the ipa again.

Comment: Yes, the provisioning profile embedded in the IPA won't include the new UDID. But that doesn't matter if you separately install the provisioning profile with that device's UDID onto the device first. That's how TestFlight does it. When you update the provisioning profile using the TestFlight interface, it allows the IPA to be installed on new devices *without* recreating the IPA. So, as I said before, this answer is wrong, because you *can* install an IPA on a device that isn't included in the embedded provisioning profile, *if* you install the updated provisioning profile onto the device.

Answer (score 3):

When using test flight, you can update your provisioning profile, then upload it by hand to test flight build (look under Permissions).

Answer (score 1):

After creating this question, I finally found [Publishing to TestFlight, new testers, do I really need to rebuild/download my provisioning profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746988/publishing-to-testflight-new-testers-do-i-really-need-to-rebuild-download-my-p?rq=1) which is the information I was looking for. I'm not sure why I couldn't search for this before though. Sorry, all!

z22 did answer the quesiton though so I'll mark him as the official response so no one in the future has to wade through another link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, When you are using TestFlight Server for sharing your app with others then you need to add his device's UDID in profile. Now suppose if you wanna create an ipa for some other UDID then again you need to add that device UDID and suppose to recreate provisioning certificate again. And then create ipa file doing Archive. From TestFlight, you need to add this new build and create App link.